# trying to identify some hardware

Tags: electrical, hardware

Does anyone know what these are? Found them on the street near a power pole that had recently had some work done.
thanks
[image]

Comment: there's tails from fish tape

Comment: Are they metal?  Look like metal.    Almost look like they could be like boot spikes for climbing up wooden poles, but they don't look broken off or how they would fit in something.

Comment: yes, metal, steel I think. And I agree they don't look broken off, and there is nothing for attaching. Maybe meant to be hammered into something? Strange also that the spread on the fins is very different between the two.

Comment: Almost look like pry wedges, but small enough to guarantee you hit your thumb with the hammer.

Comment: This is a lineworker question, not home improvement.  My guess would be that they are part of some sort of insulation piercing wire connector.

Comment: This question should be closed.... but I'd kind of like to know what they are.

Comment: I finally found some guys working, three linesmen with the local power company. None of them had any idea what these things are. The mystery goes on...